# how to create a temp table in Dremio

Tags: sql, dremio

I would like to create a temporary table as below in dremio

Select ABC into #temp_table

any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think DREMIO explicitly supports temporary tables.  However, it does have the ability to create tables on the fly from the results of the query using `create table as` (CTAS):

```
create table temp_table as
    select ABC;
```